# Stack Overflow for Teams: Question incorrectly not accepted as duplicate, how to overrule?

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-for-teams

We are introducing Stack Overflow for Teams in our company. As part of that effort, I'm trying to add FAQ's related to onboarding of new employees in the system.

The problem that I'm having is that the Stack Overflow software incorrectly marks questions as duplicate, and does not allow me to even add them to the system. Is there a way to overrule the duplicate error?

As an example, I have a number of similar-looking but different questions "How do I get access to xxx or an account for xxx".

Comment: OK, thanks for the quick responses and sorry for my mistake. Stack Overflow for teams points me to this website though ;-)
"If your question is about this website, ask it on meta (https://meta.stackexchange.com/) instead."

Comment: @Denis Can you post a screenshot of where you're seeing that?

Comment: @JoeFriend I'm unsure what 'that' is referring to, but I'm guessing the reference to stack exchange meta. Here is a ![screenshot](https://imageshack.com/a/img924/8084/Iivykl.png)

Comment: Hey Denis - are you talking about the duplicate title checker? If you could include a screenshot of the error you're getting, that'd clarify this question a bit (redact any sensitive portions of the screenshot before posting).

Comment: @denis Exactly what I needed. We will fix that link.

Comment: @JoeFriend here is a screenshot of the ![error message](https://imageshack.com/a/img922/2449/F5xuIx.png)

Comment: @denis Are you still seeing this? I've tried to reproduce it and it is quite easy for me to get around the duplicate check by changing a word in the title.